# Can't run Node application (TypeError: Invalid Version: 0.18.04)

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

When the application starts, the following error occurs.
But I cannot understand what version it may be about?
So is it about the version of what?
Please help!

```
user@ubuntu:/var/www/place$ node app.js
debug: `sails.config.express` is deprecated; use `sails.config.http` instead.
info: 
info:                .-..-.
info: 
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.12.13            |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------' 
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info: 
info: Server lifted in `/var/www/place`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

debug: -------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Tue Aug 21 2018 20:54:04 GMT+0300 (MSK)

debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] TypeError: Invalid Version: 0.18.04
    at new SemVer (/var/www/place/node_modules/semver/semver.js:293:11)
    at compare (/var/www/place/node_modules/semver/semver.js:566:10)
    at Function.gte (/var/www/place/node_modules/semver/semver.js:615:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/place/node_modules/db-migrate-pg/index.js:159:43)
    at /var/www/place/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/context.js:84:17
    at tryCatcher (/var/www/place/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/www/place/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/var/www/place/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/www/place/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/var/www/place/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/var/www/place/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/var/www/place/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/var/www/place/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
```

Comment: It looks like there are other similar errors out there related running gulp. Have you tried deleting the node modules and giving them a fresh install?

Comment: @streleckify no, just run node rebuild

Comment: @Viking777 What is the sails version. can  you post your package.json

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda - the terminal output shows Sails v0.12.13

Comment: Some further help with node and npm repair/upgrading if troubleshooting attempts still aren't working: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting